# how to read the text or doc file keeping line breaks and styles (bold,italic,underline,heading bold with large size) as in android programmatically

Tags: android, styles

how to read the text or doc file keeping line breaks and styles (bold,italic,underline,heading bold with large size) as in android app programmatically...

i know how to read text files line by line by this from assets,raw files or from sd card but i want to read file AS IT IS keeping all styles bullet points and some text in it is of large size and bold just like heading[image]

Comment: you basically need to know how to read doc and docx file, right?

Comment: yes but not just text in it without formatting...i want to keep all formatting and its encoding format to UTF-8